# Create QML Items out of DelegateModel

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to create QML Items out of a DelegateModel?

**Here is a example DelegateModel:**

```
DelegateModel
 {
    id: delegateModel
    model: ListModel
    {
        ListElement { name: "#FAFAFA"; test: "object1" }
        ListElement { name: "#000000"; test: "object2" }
    }
    delegate: Rectangle
    {
        objectName: test
        width: 50
        height: 50
        color: name
    }
    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        Utils.var_dump(items,3)
        items.create(0)
        Utils.var_dump(items.get(0),3)
    }
 }
```

**The Result should look like this:**

```
Rectangle
{
    objectName: "object1"
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "#FAFAFA"
}
Rectangle
{
    objectName: "object2"
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "#000000"
}
```

For every ListElement there is a created delegate with the inserted ListElement data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with anything that is usable to instantiate a `Model` (a `View`)

For example you could use it as a model for a `ListView`, a `GridView` or a `Repeater`. As the model provides the delegate on its own, you do not need to specify any delegate in the `View`, that instantiates it.

```
Column {
    Repeater {
        model: delegateModel
        // delegate: ... <--- Nothing here! Uses the delegate from the Model.
    }
}
```

If you use the `create(index)`-Method, the delegate will be created, but has no parent, so it is not displayed. So you need to set the parent, to have it shown:

```
Button {
    onClicked:  {
        for (var a = 0; a < dm.items.count; a++) {
            var o = dm.items.create(a)
            o.parent = r
        }
    }
}
```

You need to be aware, that the `DelegateModel` (without `Package` and `Parts`) can't be used in multiple views, as each entry/delegate can be instantiated only once at the same time. If you want to have that,
consider using a [`QSortFilterProxyModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) to filter the stuff, and use as much `Views` that provide their own delegates, as you want.